# tmux deleting currently displayed content when pressing ^L

Tags: tmux

I have the following options in my `.tmuxrc` so the PuTTY scrollback still works.

```
setw -g alternate-screen off
set -g terminal-overrides "xterm*:kLFT5=\eOD:kRIT5=\eOC:kUP5=\eOA:kDN5=\eOB:smkx@:rmkx@:smcup@:rmcup@"
```

This works fine and when switching tmux to copy mode, I can scroll back into tmux' scrollback buffer.
When generating long output, the old output which is not visible anymore can be accessed by scrolling back using tmux' copy mode or the scrollbar in PuTTY.

However, when pressing `^L` to clear the screen, the currently displayed text is **completely erased**, both from PuTTY's and from tmux' scrollback. This is rather annoying and I'd like to know why it's happening and what I can do to prevent this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything displayed does not enter the scrollback buffer on putty or tmux until it is pushed off the viewport.